# How can I restart my routers DHCP to the first starting address?

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, dhcp

I just changed my router's IP from `192.168.1.1` to `10.1.1.1`.  My local IP before was `192.168.1.124` and now it is `10.1.1.124`.

How can I make it `10.1.1.100` (100 is the starting number for my DHCP server.  I have done release/renew a few times but to no avail.

Comment: Your DHCP server? You mean on the router?　What brand of router?

Comment: Your question is confusing.  is your router set at .124, or a pc connected to it?

Comment: a pc connected to it. another pc connected to it ends in 136 which is not following the .100, .101 sequence i expected

Comment: Your router may have DHCP setting that you can change. The DHCP setting usually requires you to enter the starting IP and the ending IP (or how many IP slots available after the starting IP).

If you are worried about the IP being in-sequence, perhaps setting Static IP is in order? (Some Router supports Static-IP via DHCP by entering the Mac address of the computer)